# Is there a GIT api that can tell if a specific line of a file has a whitespace only change

Tags: git, lint

Is there a GIT api that can tell if a specific line (say given line no.) of a file has a whitespace only change? I'm writing a rule in lint (ArcanistLinter) that would alert if certain lines have only whitespace changes, and they're not adjacent to any real change (say they got modified by the editor).

Comment: See `--word-diff` in git-diff(1).

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly. There is, however, a way to request a diff that omits whitespace-only changes:

```
git diff --ignore-space-change
```

This will omit lines where only whitespace was changed (with the exception of creating whitespace in between two non-whitespace tokens that were previously adjacent, e.g. `foobar` -> `foo bar`).

You could compare that diff result with the regular diff to find which items are present in the latter but not the former.

Comment: I need to know the line numbers as well. git diff/show both omit line numbers. Is there a way I could get the lines (and their line numbers) that have real changes, and overall (including whitespace) changes with lines (and their line numbers)?

Comment: diff format notes where the beginning of a diff occurs; it's in the metadata at the beginning of the diff segment (the `@@ -#,# +#,# @@` portion). There are two number pairs; the first one is the starting line and the line count of the 'before' diff; the second one is the starting line and the line count of the 'after' diff.

Comment: If you use `-U0` to specify 0 lines of context, then the starting line number will refer to the line number of the first actual modified line.